# inconsistent logic in probabilistic graphical models

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

suppose we have graphical model X>Y>Z.

It would be written in this form:

```
P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)*P(Y|X)*P(Z|Y)
```

However, I have seen people would write it down in this form:

```
P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)*P(Y|X)*P(Z|X,Y)
```

if both things are correct then we could say:

```
P(Z|Y) = P(Z|X,Y)
```

What would defacto mean, that Probability of Z given the joint probability of X and Y is equal to probability of Z given probability of Y. What means, joint probability of X, Y is exactly the same as the probability of Y. As I understand, the joint probability of X and Y are not the same as the marginal probability of Y.

Am I wrong? And if am not, which is the correct way to write it down?

Answer (score 1):

The equality
$$P(X,Y,Z) = P(X) P(Y \mid X) P(Z \mid X,Y)$$
holds for any joint distribution.

Your graphical model encodes a special subset of joint distributions, namely those that satisfy
$$P(X,Y,Z) = P(X) P(Y \mid X) P(Z \mid Y).$$
As you noted, you can equivalently state that your graphical model considers joint distributions that satisfy
$$P(Z \mid Y) = P(Z \mid X,Y).$$
This is sometimes expressed as "$Z$ and $X$ are conditionally independent given $Y$."
This is also equivalent to
$$P(Z, X \mid Y) = P(Z \mid Y) P(X \mid Y).$$

Nothing here implies "joint probability of $(X,Y)$ is exactly the same as the probability of $Y$."

Answer (score 1):

The second statement $P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)\,P(Y\mid X)\,P(Z\mid X,Y)$ is true in general for events

$P(Z\mid Y) = P(Z\mid X,Y)$ is a special case of conditional independence ("given $Y$, you have $Z$ independent of $X$") which may or may not be true.  If it is, some people write $Z \perp X \mid Y$.  Others might write $X \leftarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ and this may be the kind of thing you were suggesting with $X>Y>Z$, namely that any dependency between $X$ and $Z$ is fully expressed by $Y$